# Receiving DeprecationWarning: Using Buffer without `new` will soon stop working

Tags: node.js, buffer, deprecation-warning

I am writing an express server, and since I upgraded my node to 7.1.x release, I have been receiving the following warning:

> (node:23488) DeprecationWarning: Using Buffer without `new` will soon
>   stop working. Use `new Buffer()`, or preferably `Buffer.from()`,
>   `Buffer.allocUnsafe()` or `Buffer.alloc()` instead.

I don't recall using a `Buffer` anywhere. I just know that I have the `log-file-rotator` module initialised in the application, which might be the only thing relating to buffer.

```
const fileStream = require('file-stream-rotator')

const LOG_PATH = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'logs')
const PORT = process.env.npm_package_config_port || 4000

let logFileStream = fileStream.getStream({
  date_format: 'YYYYMMDD',
  filename: path.join(LOG_PATH, 'access-%DATE%.log'),
  frequency: 'daily',
  verbose: false
})
```

But, looking in [their source repo](https://github.com/holidayextras/file-stream-rotator/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Buffer), I do not notice any statement with a `Buffer` call.

Why the error, and how to resolve it?

Comment: What the version installed of file-stream-rotator ? npm list file-stream-rotator  make sure you have the latest

Comment: @Dafuck https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-stream-rotator The project is no longer maintained, and the last release was 4 months ago.

Comment: have you tried another package ? https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-rotate or https://www.npmjs.com/package/rotator if you want to keep this package update it by hand.

Comment: Have you tried to update by hand the moment dependencies ?

Comment: I ran a `grep -nrF 'Buffer' node_modules` and it returns me over 32k lines.

Comment: I just try your code, with node v7.1.0 and 7.0.0 and i've no warning with the following code http://pastebin.com/R091xrMH , the problem comes from another package i think

Answer (score 2):

I am on OSX which has a limited grep. I installed `ack` using HomeBrew:

```
brew install ack
```

Then ran the following search for instances of `Buffer(...)` not preceded by `new`:

```
ack --js '(?<!new) Buffer\(' --noignore-dir=node_modules/
```

You can alternatively output to a file with:

```
ack --js '(?<!new) Buffer\(' --noignore-dir=node_modules/ > ~/Desktop/buffer.txt
```

Then examine that for uses of Buffer that might trigger that warning such as:

```
var a = Buffer(something)
```

Once you have a list of packages with issues then you can find out what depends on them with:

```
npm ls
```

This prints out the package tree where you can find which primary package may need updating or an issue filed.